# Changing the order of days

Tags: r, dataframe, sequence, dayofweek

I am unable to present my days of the week in a chronological order, and while visualizing the data, it doesn't looks right.

I tried using ordered statement, but it shows me an error, please help

This is my code -

```
avg_ride_day <- cyclistic_data %>%
  filter(bike_type != "docked_bike") %>%
  group_by(user_type, day_of_week) %>%
  summarise(avg_time_min = mean(ride_length)/60, median_time = median(ride_length)/60, 
            max_time = max(ride_length)/60, min_time = min(ride_length)/60) %>%
  arrange(day_of_week)
```

And this is how it is displayed -
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUuCs.png)

Comment: ''day_of_week' is of type character and is sorted alphabetically in your output. If you want the sorting to be mo-tue-wed- etc. you could convert 'day_of_week' to a sorted factor before calling 'arrange'

Comment: Make it a factor and provide the levels, `factor(day_of_week, levels= c("Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"))` and then arrange (move "Sun" to the end if you want the days to start on Mondays)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
expl <- data.frame(days = c("tue", "mon", "wed"))

library(dplyr)

expl %>% 
  mutate(days = factor(days, levels = c("mon", "tue", "wed"))) %>% 
  arrange(days)
```

returns:

```
  days
1  mon
2  tue
3  wed
```